# PHP get cut of the jackpot

Tags: php

I am creating a jackpot website using real money. It is free to play there, but we will take x% of the total jackpot. I am getting the total jackpot out of different rows in the database. It could look like this:

```
name    | depositedValue
------------------------
Player1 | 50$
Player2 | 20$
..
```

Some code that maybe can help:

```
$AllDeposits = $jackpot->getBank();
foreach($AllDeposits as $deposit){
echo $deposit->depositedValue;
}
$cutPercentage = 2;
$cut = ????
```

Comment: Um... and your question is...?

Comment: Note that this is illegal in most parts of the world. Commercial gambling services are typically very restricted and controlled. Fines are _huge_.

Comment: @BobKaufman, How to get the cut of - total jackpot: 100$ - 2$ cut?

Comment: Consider making that more clear in your question.

Comment: So you'll take my real money, for free? A bargain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
$AllDeposits = $jackpot->getBank();
$cutPercentage = 2;
$cut = 0;
foreach($AllDeposits as $deposit){
    echo $deposit->depositedValue;
    $cut += $deposit->depositedValue * ($cutPercentage / 100.0);
}
```